# Print field from reference of reference (node)

Tags: theming, entities

I use the module "entity reference" and I ave "Inline Entity Form" in the node. The first reference has another reference inside. In total there are 3 nests, a grandfather, a father and son.
In node.tpl the first parent node how can I print a field of his nephew?

```
- Node.1
-- Ref. Node.2
--- Ref. Node.3
```

I want to print a Node.3 field's in Node.1

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

There is always more than one way to solve a problem in drupal.  How easy those ways are is up for debate, but they exist.

You could:

1. Make a view with those reference fields as relationships and a nid context filter that would recognize the Node.1 end of the relationships.  Set this view to have a block display, and A) put the block on the page with a [context](https://www.drupal.org/project/context) or B) summon the [view to be rendered by name](https://www.drupal.org/node/951442#comment-5381336) in your tpl. Or with the function [views_embed_view](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_embed_view/7.x-3.x)
2. Make [database fetches](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_select/7.x) or [entity field queries](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21entity.inc/class/EntityFieldQuery/7.x) directly in your node.tpl.php.  This is uncouth, as such logic should not be put in the theme layer, but functional.
3. Forget about node.tpl.php entirely and do this in [panels](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels).  I'm pretty sure it supports using referenced fields.

The `echo $view->render('block_view');` method would be my suggestion to you.  Views is a very powerful module, has built in [theming overrides](https://www.drupal.org/node/1918334) (and more if you want [more tpls](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/theme!views-view-fields.tpl.php/7.x-3.x)) and can do all sorts of rewrites and manipluations while laying things out for you.  Add the ability to conjure it's database bending powers from your tpl with just 6 lines of code, and it is stupendous.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention... I already used Views metod, and is ok, but for reasons I do not need to say, I need to use the method override node.tpl

Comment: But did you do this in your node.tpl.php?  https://www.drupal.org/node/951442#comment-5381336

Comment: I don't understand how to use the methods that you said.
Amongst other things, I need print "rate" (with 5 stars) for any node3 (the nephew).